# Does it make sense to replace ternary operator with a React useMemo function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator, memoization

I am having a [ternary operator](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) inside my React prop:

```
const isItemOne = item.type === 'Item one';

return (
  <ChildComponent
    myProp={
      isItemOne
        ? generateFunctionOne(itemOne.id, location)
        : generateFunctionTwo(itemTwo.url)
    }
  />
```

Does it make sense, in this case to replace the ternary operator with a function and use [React useMemo hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) here like:

```
const setValue = useMemo(() => {
  if (isItemOne) {
    return generateFunctionOne(itemOne.id, location);
  }
  return generateFunctionTwo(itemTwo.url);
}, [itemOne.id, itemTwo.url]);
```

Comment: `useMemo` is for caching result of expensive calculation between re-renders, it is not (directly) related to ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to replace the ternary operator with a function and use the React `useMemo` hook in this case.

But I think it makes more sense if you add `isItemOne` in dependencies because useMemo will not re-evaluate when the `isItemOne` dependency changes.

```
const setValue = useMemo(() => {
  if (isItemOne) {
    return generateFunctionOne(itemOne.id, location);
  }
  return generateFunctionTwo(itemTwo.url);
}, [isItemOne, itemOne.id, itemTwo.url]);
```